# Matplotlib: Change math font size

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am making some plots with matplotlib, and I've come across a problem with the TeX rendering. It seems that the mathtext x-height is is a bit smaller than the normal Bitstream Vera Sans. See the following example:

```
x = linspace(0, 30, 300);
y = 0.5*rand(300)+20/(numpy.power(x-15, 2)+4);
xlabel(r'$\omega$ (rad$\cdot$Hz)');
ylabel(r'Intensity$^2$');
title(r'Why is $mathtext$ so much smaller than normal text?');
```

[image: Plot of some random data illustrating the issue.]

As you can see, it's particularly noticeable with greek letters and numbers. Ideally, I'd be able to define some scaling factor that would just make the math text a bit bigger at each font size. Is there any way to do this simply? I do *not* want to simply use Computer Modern everywhere. I also do not want to compile a new Tex math font, if that's even possible.

One solution that I *would* be on board with is using sans-serif fonts for the greek letters and numerals, but for whatever reason, matplotlib ignores formatting on those:

```
title('Why does $mat\mathsf{plot}lib$ ignore formatting for $\mathsf{2}$ ($\mathsf{two}), $\mathbf{2}$ ($\mathbf{two}) and $\mathsf{\omega}$?')
```

[image: Title changed]

I assume it's something to do with the nature of how these things are typeset, but is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Are using the internal math render or an external latex installation?

Comment: I think internal math render. I haven't changed it from the default. rcParams['pgf.texsystem'] resolves to 'xelatex', but I don't really know what that's used for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#fonts):

> Additionally, you can use `\mathdefault{...}` or its alias
>   `\mathregular{...}` to use the font used for regular text outside of
>   mathtext. There are a number of limitations to this approach, most
>   notably that far fewer symbols will be available, but it can be useful
>   to make math expressions blend well with other text in the plot.

Comment: Beautiful. You can apparently just add rcParams['mathtext.default']='regular', and that sets the text to the normal font. I think I had tried that before but I must have messed up the implementation. That works now.

Comment: Looking at the docs is always a good idea

Answer (score 3):

Try setting

```
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

which will try to use an external LaTeX installation, rather than the built in mathtext renderer. See [this wiki](http://www.scipy.org/Wiki/Cookbook/Matplotlib/UsingTex) (even though it is a tad out-dated) and the discussion on [issue #1336](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1366)

Another option, if you are targeting LaTeX, is to use pstricks.

Comment: This is very much not ideal. It sets all text rendering to be done by TeX (something I don't want), which sets the font to be Computer Modern. It does introduce sans-serif numbers, which is nice, but formatting is still ignored on greek letters.

Comment: does strait up TeX support the formatting on the greek letters? (That is make a .tex file and see if it renders as you expect there).  I suspect you might also be running into issues with font, in that not all fonts contain glyphs for all styles of all symbols.

Comment: I can check in a bit, but I'd prefer to use Myriad Pro, which does have glyphs for greek letters, but I don't think it's supported in TeX without me specifically compiling it. I am assuming that the better way to go is to find a way to scale tex fonts when they are used.

Comment: Another option, if you are dumping this into an LaTeX document, is to use pstricks to do the formatting later.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, actually. In the end, I'm going to use the 'regular' option, because the figures don't go exclusively in Latex files, but good to know about PStricks - since I could always add that into my workflow (have some 'make the fonts look nice' module or something and export to EPS)

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be fixed in matplotlib 2. See issue

[Different font size between math mode and regular text #7778](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7778).

and

[Matplotlib: correct math font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555340/matplotlib-correct-math-font-size).