# matplotlib Legend sign and text are not aligned

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am facing this issue while putting subscript in the legend of my graph. If I don't use subscript in the legend text, it all looks fine and the handle and text are aligned, but with subscript, the font of the text changes and also, it gets stuck on the top of the legend box. This is how I am setting the legend

```
        ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.12),
             ncol=4,prop={'size':16})
```

and the legend is

```
        legend_labels=['BR:$K_r$=5%',"BR:$K_r$=10%","Tape:$K_r$=5%","Tape:$K_r$=20%","HDD:$K_r$=5%","HDD:$K_r$=20%","SSD:$K_r$=5%","SSD:$K_r$=20%"]
```

I have also seen multiple questions about alignment of text and legend on stackoverflow but the solutions suggested did not work for me. I tried getting text from the legend and setting alignment to 'center' to no avail.

Here is the minimum working example.

```
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *

    subplot(211)
    plot([1,2,3], label="$test_1$")
    plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
    legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.,prop={'size':18})
    show()
```

I am using python 2.7.6.

Comment: Can you insert a screenshot of what you get and how it is different from your expectations? Because everything looks fine to me.

Comment: the asker wants the baseline of both labels to be the same (i.e. the "line" that the main text is sitting on) whereas currently the subscript is causing the baseline of that label to be shifted up

Comment: Then everything works for me, see http://imgur.com/AxmLv8Y

Comment: Andrey, I saw your image and it looked perfect. So, I saved my image (showing legend text not aligned) and reopened. AMAZINGLY, it does not show the legend text sticking to the roof :/. Now my problem is why the subscripted portion appear in a different font than the rest of the legend?

Comment: As of February 2023, I think the MWE you had actually aligns text and sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in fonts comes from the math mode: surrounding text with dollar signs tells matplotlib to preprocess the text with LaTeX, and LaTeX math font (Computer Modern) is different from Liberation Sans (or whatever font matplotlib uses for plain text). The easiest way to circumvent this misconception is to use math mode *just for indices*:

```
plot([1,2,3], label="test$_1$")
```

Then math font will be used just for indices:

[image]

Comment: But, in my case I need to subscript a letter. If you replace     plot([1,2,3], label="$test_1$")
by     plot([1,2,3], label="$test_r$") for font size 18, 'r' looks really small compared to the rest of the legend text, which I don't want.

Comment: Then you might want to set `mathtext.default` to `regular` (as per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569071/matplotlib-change-math-font-size-and-then-go-back-to-default)

Comment: I had the same problem explained in the comment and the solution was the second answer of the link provided (i.e. non the accepted answer but rather the one by mgab)