# Matplotlib: correct math font size

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, math-mode

Math text in matplotlib is rendered smaller than the regular text as show by

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'Variable $\alpha$')
```

Further details on this problem are found in [Matplotlib: Change math font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836050/matplotlib-change-math-font-size).

The accepted solution was setting math font to regular font.
But then variable in math mode are not italic as they should be.

I need variables in math mode and of the same size as text.

How can this be achieved and why is this not the default?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have reported this issue at 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7778.

There I learned that this is fixed in matplotlib 2.0.

This got released and it works!

See [Changes to the default style](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/users/dflt_style_changes.html#figure-size-font-size-and-screen-dpi).